# resize multiplefile with illustrator

Tags: file, adobe-illustrator

I have a question, I have 30-day illustrator cs6 and I want to resize a lot of file from 30x40 to 200x400 (this is an example), there is a way for do it automatically?with a script?

Comment: if you just want to resize files there are plenty of free / libre open source software programmes available for batch processing image files. although I wouldn't recommend going from a lower resolution (30x40) to a higher one (200x400), your results will be poor. I recommend http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Comment: what I want to do is resive artboard, I solved whit action and batch :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution

1. Open your file
2. Go to File -> Export
3. Check "Use Artboard" and save
4. In resolution use "Custom" and insert value of 720.

Lastly click ok and enjoy 300X400